# way to change location inside Saga in React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, redux-saga

For this i try use connected-react-router, and history paskage, and react-router-redux.
but their ways doesn't work. if someone know ways to do it, please share. Have a good day!

Comment: Why do you even want to do this. You should change the location in your component. code. Keep the redux-saga as no side effect function

Comment: From what I've gathered there's no right way or easy way to do this. One way you can accomplish this is by having your component react to something in your redux state and have an effect that navigates. You could also send the history or push function with an action, but this path will lead to other problems later if you for instance want to serialize your actions.

Comment: Most of the utilities provided by react-router exist within the scope of your components.  You can access them in any component which is inside of a Router component because the Router serves as a context provider.  Your sagas do not have access to React contexts.  So you are trying to do something that’s beyond what these packages are designed to do.  You could definitely hack together a solution — for example setting window.location in a saga — but I don’t recommend it.